# How to save entity in DB with empty string value

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have an entity with property:

```
/**
 * @var string The title attr
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $title = '';
```

And form type is:

```
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

But when I get this empty value from `form` and try to save this entity to the DB I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title'
> cannot be null

Why is it `null`? I set this property to the empty string `''`, and not `null`.

How can I store this entity in the DB with empty string `''` (and without `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)`)?

Answer (score 2):

Set default column value as empty string:

```
/**
 * @var string The title attr
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default":""})
 */
protected $title = '';
```

Comment: Unrelated to me, but really neat solution :)

Comment: I try to do this, but it doesn't work for me. I think this is because I get `title` value from `form`, I updated question, added form type.

Comment: @Victor So how about setting [empty_data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data)?

Comment: @bartek Work only when I use space: `'empty_data' => ' ',`, but when I use empty string `''` error is same

Comment: @ferodss No, it's Doctrine mapping

Comment: Not sure if its outdated or anything, but the solution for me was to do in entity mapping: `options={"default":""}` and in form field options: `'empty_data' => false`